# pclose() returns SIGPIPE intermittently

Tags: linux, multithreading, signals, posix, popen

When the following C program is executed, and `SIGUSR1` is sent to the running process repeatedly, the `pclose()` call will sometimes return 13. 13 corresponds to `SIGPIPE` on my system.

**Why does this happen?**

I am using `while true; do kill -SIGUSR1 <process-id>; done` to send `SIGUSR1` to the program. The program is executed on Ubuntu 14.04.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void handler(int i) {}

void* task(void*)
{
    FILE *s;
    char b [BUFSIZ];
    while (1) {
        if ((s = popen("echo hello", "r")) == NULL) {
            printf("popen() failed\n");
        }
        while (fgets(b, BUFSIZ, s) != NULL) ;
        if (int r = pclose(s)) {
            printf("pclose() failed (%d)\n", r);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct sigaction action;
    action.sa_handler = handler;
    sigemptyset(&action.sa_mask);
    action.sa_flags = 0;
    sigaction(SIGUSR1, &action, NULL);

    pthread_t tid;
    pthread_create(&tid, 0, task, NULL);
    pthread_join(tid, NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when `fgets` gets interrupted by the signal. The program doesn't read the pipe to the end and closes it. The other program then SIGPIPEs.

The correct pipe reading operation is:

```
 do {
    while (fgets(b, BUFSIZ, s) != NULL) ;
 } while (errno == EINTR);
```

Comment: Thanks. I should have read the `fgets()` documentation closer: "Upon successful completion, fgets() shall return s. If the stream is at end-of-file, the end-of-file indicator for the stream shall be set and fgets() shall return a null pointer. **If a read error occurs, the error indicator for the stream shall be set, fgets() shall return a null pointer, and shall set errno to indicate the error.**"